# What type of database is used in mendix?

Tags: mendix

Mendix is a low code development platform. I want to know which type of relational database does it uses?

Comment: See https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/data-storage#2-supported-databases and https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/system-requirements#databases

Answer (score 2):

Mendix studio pro uses HSQL by default as database, if you are using Mendix cloud, then it uses Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the Mendix cloud then you will currently be using postgres 13.

[Here are a list of supported databases.](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/data-storage)

These can be used when you deploy on premise.

Also check out the Mendix forum and community slack if you have anymore questions.

Mendix Forum: https://forum.mendix.com

Mendix Community Slack: [https://join.slack.com/t/mendixcommunity/shared_invite/zt-hwhwkcxu-~59ywyjqHlUHXmrw5heqpQ](https://join.slack.com/t/mendixcommunity/shared_invite/zt-hwhwkcxu-%7E59ywyjqHlUHXmrw5heqpQ)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.